# MNIST For ML Beginners - Why is "one-hot" vector length 11?

Tags: tensorflow

If you carefully count the digits displayed in the tutorial, also shown below, you'll see that it has length 11.  The indexes 0 through 9 stand for each digit, a total of 10. However, what's the significance of the 11th position shown below?

Also, the code is defined with length 10, [60000,10].

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a typo, do not worry about it (actually this is not the only typo there). If you will check the shape of the data `mnist.train.labels.shape` you will get `(55000, 10)` which is not the same as they claim `(60000, 10)`.

Also this shape of the data shows you that the length of one-hot vector is 10.

Comment: It looks like the documentation has been corrected.